# How to read multiple lines from socket stream?

Tags: php, imap

I want to retrieve email from gmails' imap server but the problem is that the responses from the server are multiple lines long (as demonstrated [here](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/imap.shtml)) and fgets only retrieves one line.

I've tried using fgets, fread, socket_read but none of them work so either i'm using the wrong method or using the methods incorrectly. I also tried [this](http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/) tutorial but it didn't work either. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks and i'm really sorry if this is an amateur question.

Code:

```
<?php

$stuff = fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com',993);
$reply = fgets($stuff,4096);
echo 'connection: '.$reply.'<br/>';

$request = fputs($stuff,"a1 LOGIN MyUserName Password\r\n");
$receive = socket_read($stuff, 4096);

echo 'login: '.$receive.'<br/>';


$request = fputs($stuff,"a2 EXAMINE INBOX\r\n");
$reply = '';

while(!feof($stuff))
    $reply .= fread($stuff, 4096);

echo $reply;



/*
$request = fputs($stuff,'a3 FETCH 1 BODY[]\r\n');
$reply = fgets($stuff);
echo $reply;
*/
?>
```

Max's answer below works. This is my implementation of it.

```
private function Response($instructionNumber)
{
    $end_of_response = false;

    while (!$end_of_response)
    {
        $line = fgets($this->connection,self::responseSize);
        $response .= $line.'<br/>';

        if(preg_match("/$instructionNumber (OK|NO|BAD)/", $response,$responseCode))
            $end_of_response = true;
    }

    return array('code' => $responseCode[1],
        'response'=>$response);
}
```

Comment: Sockets transmit streams of octets, not strings. PHP probably doesn't care a bit about the line separators. Your code looks fine to me, although AFAIK you shouldn't be using `feof` because it reads until the connection is terminated (which would probably be a timeout)

Comment: The PHP manual itself mentions that `fgets` reads a single line of input: "Gets a line from file pointer."

Comment: Thanks for the note on `feof`, I was having a timeout issue when I tried that bit of code.

Comment: Yes, `fgets`, which is *'File, GET me a String'* (note the caps), but not `fread`

Comment: You generally don't want to use `feof` when dealing with sockets. You just want to keep calling `fread`, put it in a buffer, then handle the part of the buffer you can handle, and go back to fread.

Comment: Wow, I think that last bit might just do the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you know to stop reading when you get the OK/BAD/NO response for the tag you sent. If you send `a1 LOGIN ...` you stop when you get `a1 OK/BAD/NO ...`.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I wrote PHP, and I don't know that much about IMAP, but if it's anything like NNTP, your code would look a bit like this (wrote it in the SO editor, might be bugged) :

```
$buffer = '';
function read_line($socket) {
    global $buffer;
    while (strpos($buffer, "\n") === false)
        $buffer .= fread($socket, 1024);

    $lineEnd = strpos($buffer, "\n");
    $line = substr($buffer, 0, $lineEnd-1);
    $buffer = substr($buffer, $lineEnd);

    return $line;
}

function send_line($socket, $line) {
    fwrite($socket, $line);
}

$socket = fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com',993);
$welcome = read_line($socket);

send_line("a1 LOGIN MyUserName Password\r\n");
$reply = read_line($socket);

send_line("a2 EXAMINE INBOX\r\n");
while (($reply = trim(read_line($socket))) != '.') {
    echo $reply.PHP_EOL;
}

echo "Done";
```

The basic concepts are :

- Always buffer all incoming data. PHP doesn't handle lines very well, so do the splitting yourself.
- Don't randomly read everything, but know what to expect. You expect one welcome line, `LOGIN` has one reply, and `EXAMINE INBOX` keeps outputting data until there's a single dot, so immediately stop reading once you see that.
- You'll most likely want a simple function to take care of the reading. You could even write another function to make it easy:

---

```
function read_block($socket) {
    $block = '';
    while ('.' != trim($reply = read_line($socket)) {
        $block .= $reply;
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: I've got something like this going on. The while loops cause timeout problems. I used `$reply = fread($socket,1000000)` and formatted `$reply` which works but it's a disgusting primitive solution :/

Comment: Generally, you know to stop reading when you get the OK/BAD/NO response for the tag you sent.  If you send a1 LOGIN.... you stop when you get a1 OK/BAD/NO ...

Comment: @Max - I can't believe i'd missed that. Your answer solved it! Could you please write it out separately?

Comment: Done.  Beware about IMAP literals though, which will cause you pain if you're doing this from scratch.  Literals are the `{n}` notation where it will tell you the n bytes are to be taken literally (like a message body).